# Newly created chrome profile won't load in

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I run this code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\micha\Desktop\Visual_projects\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options = chrome_options)

driver.get("https://store.steampowered.com/")
```

This error pops up : 
[12216:1336:0411/232857.718:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()

Could someone please help me. I don't know what is wrong but the program won't open the new profile I created. Any help would be appreciated.

I searched everywhere how to fix this error but I think the guides are outdated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly answer to your question. But I found this [link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started) very useful.

Also, I see you are trying to include user dir options. Actually, this is not required since it creates a temporary directory while launching `chromedriver.exe`.

To know options for `chromedriver.exe` - `chromedriver.exe -h` is of great help.

See example below which works great at my end. Also, I prefer to use paths without spaces in windows, it helps keep things simple.
If you use `--verbose` instead of `--log-level=INFO` you will get all logs.

In the chromedriver log, you can see the default arguments given to the `chromedriver.exe`.

```py
import time, os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

exePath = './driver/chromedriver.exe'
logPath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'logs','chromedriver.log')
serviceArgs = ["--log-level=INFO", "--readable-timestamp", "--append-log"]

# service = Service(executable_path=exePath, log_path=logPath, service_args=serviceArgs)
service = Service(log_path=logPath, service_args=serviceArgs)
service.start()
print(service.service_url)
print(service.process.pid)

# driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url)
# Update to remove infobars and save password popups

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
prefs = {"profile.password_manager_enabled": False, "credentials_enable_service": False}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
caps = options.to_capabilities()

driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, desired_capabilities=caps)

# driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:63404')
driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.get("https://github.com")
time.sleep(3)
driver.back()
time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
service.stop()
```

`service.stop()` terminates the `chromedriver.exe` or else it will keep running in the background.
Folder structure at my end is like below:

```
rootDir
--driver/chromedriver.exe
--testchromedriver.py (with above code)
```

Also, created as `killchromedriver.py` file to terminate all `chromedriver.exe` instances in case they are running in background.

```py
import psutil # pip install psutil

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if(process.name() == 'chromedriver.exe'):
        process.terminate()
        print('chromedriver.exe was running and is now terminated')
```

Update:
Adding options to remove the infobars and save password popups

Comment: Extensive list of chromium command line switches can be found https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches

Answer (score -1):

Updated my chrome browser to version 81 so had to update chrome webdriver too. But after the update it has started giving this error to me also. 
Here is the code, i have removed other methods/functions from it.

```
from selenium import  webdriver
from time import sleep
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '../..')
from secrets import username, password

class MyBot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()

bot=MyBot()
```

[3220:14704:0416/145232.014:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()

Comment: It also comes in my case like `[8840:13028:0417/081702.218:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()` but it doesn't block me to run tests.